# Mongoid access issue

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I am writing an app to with a DB inside. I am using MongoId. it's just one database with only one entry. I am saving a token in this database

api.rb

```
    def get_wink_token
      retrieve_token.present? ? retrieve_token : new_token
    end

    def new_token
      RestClient.get "#{ENV['DOMAIN']}/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=#{ENV['CLIENT_ID']}&redirect_uri=#{ENV['REDIRECT_URI']}"
      token_credentials = RestClient.post "#{ENV['DOMAIN']}/oauth2/token", credentials, headers
      access_token = JSON.parse(token_credentials)['data']['access_token']
      TokenDb.any_in(:name => 'Token').destroy_all
      TokenDb.create(name:'Token', token:access_token)
      access_token
    end

    def retrieve_token
      TokenDb.where(:name => 'Token').present? ? TokenDb.where(:name => 'Token').first[:token] : nil
    end
```

the process to get the token through `new_token` is working fine. My issue is that I have a crash when doing the TokenDb.where. the present generate the crash.

the TokenDB class is defined as below:

```
class TokenDb
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  include Mongoid::Attributes::Dynamic

  field :name,      type:String
  field :token,     type:String

  validates_presence_of :name, :token
end
```

What I am trying to do is checking if the database `tokenDb`have an entry called Token and retrieve the data, if not, I generate a new key

```
2017-03-13 23:18:08 - NoMethodError - undefined method `each' for nil   /Users/sebastien/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/blank.rb:22:in `present?'
    /Users/sebastien/smarthome/models/credentials.rb:23:in `retrieve_token'
```

the issue happened in the TokenDb.where... line

Any idea ?

Comment: What errors are you getting? Are they at the client-side or server-side, or both?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `find_by` and rescue the exception when it does not exist:

```
def get_wink_token
  TokenDb.find_by(name: 'token').token
rescue Mongoid::Errors::DocumentNotFound
  create_token
end

def create_token
  RestClient.get "#{ENV['DOMAIN']}/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=#{ENV['CLIENT_ID']}&redirect_uri=#{ENV['REDIRECT_URI']}"
  token_credentials = RestClient.post "#{ENV['DOMAIN']}/oauth2/token", credentials, headers
  access_token = JSON.parse(token_credentials)['data']['access_token']
  TokenDb.any_in(:name => 'Token').destroy_all
  TokenDb.create(name: 'Token', token: access_token)
  access_token
end
```

Although using a database just for that is overkill...